# If $P$ is non-atomic, then show that for every $\varepsilon>0$, we have $B\subseteq A$ such that $0<P(B)<\varepsilon$.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-verification

Currently I am reading [Dembo's Probability Theory notes.](http://statweb.stanford.edu/%7Eadembo/stat-310b/lnotes.pdf)

At page $9,$ the author provided exercise $1.1.8.$

> **Exercise $1.1.8$** Suppose $P$ is non-atomic and $A \in \mathcal{F}$ with $P(A) > 0.$
>
> (a) Show that for every $\varepsilon>0$, we have $B\subseteq A$ such that $0<P(B)<\varepsilon$.

---

Definition $1.1.7$ We say that a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ is **non-atomic**, or alternatively call $P$ **non-atomic** if $P(A) > 0$ implies the existence of $B \in  \mathcal{F}$, $B \subseteq A$ with
$$0 < P(B) < P(A).$$

---

My attempt:

By atomicity of $P,$ there exists $A_1\subseteq A$ such that
$$0<P(A_1)<P(A).$$
Express
$$A = A_1 \cup (A\setminus A_1).$$
If either $A_1$ or $A\setminus A_1$ have measures less than $\varepsilon,$ then we are done.
Otherwise, assume that $P(A_1)\geq \varepsilon$ and $P(A\setminus A_1)\geq \varepsilon.$

By non-atomicity of $P$ on $A\setminus A_1,$ there exists $A_2\subseteq A \setminus A_1$ such that $0<P(A_2)<P(A\setminus A_1)$ and
$$A\setminus A_1 = A_2 \cup [(A\setminus A_1)\setminus A_2].$$
If either $P(A_2)<\varepsilon$ or $P[(A\setminus A_1)\setminus A_2]< \varepsilon,$ then we are done.
Assume otherwise.

If at some point we have $A_N\subseteq A$ such that $P(A_N)<\varepsilon,$ then we are done.

Otherwise, we obtain a sequence of subsets $(A_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ of $A$ such that
$$A = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$$
where the union is disjoint and $P(A_n)\geq \varepsilon$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}.$
However, by countably additivity of $P,$ we have
$$P(A) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(A_n) \geq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \varepsilon = \infty,$$
a contradiction.
Therefore, the process must terminate and hence there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $P(A_N)<\varepsilon.$

---

Is my attempt correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably avoid using Reductio ad absurdum by noticing that 
$P(A_N) < P(A)-\varepsilon N$ thus your algorithm stops after at most $\left[\frac{P(A)}{\varepsilon}\right]+1$ steps.

Comment: The maximal number of steps should depend on $\varepsilon$ and $P(A)$, not $N$

Comment: yes I probably meant, $P(A)/\varepsilon$, I correct my answer