# If $\mathbb{P}$ is non-atomic, prove that if $0<a<\mathbb{P}(A),$ then there exists $B\subseteq A$ with $\mathbb{P}(B)=a.$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

The following exercise is taken from [Amir Dembo Probability theory's lecture note.](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~adembo/stat-310b/lnotes.pdf)

> Suppose $\mathbb{P}$ is non-atomic and $A\in \mathcal{F}$ with $\mathbb{P}(A)>0.$
>
> 1. Show that for every $\epsilon>0,$ we have $B\subseteq A$ such that $0<\mathbb{P}(B)<\epsilon.$
> 2. Prove that if $0<a<\mathbb{P}(A),$ then there exists $B\subseteq A$ with $\mathbb{P}(B)=a.$

I solved the first problem in this [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2979195/if-p-is-non-atomic-then-show-that-for-every-varepsilon0-we-have-b-subse). 
The following is my attempt to part $2.$

Let $\epsilon_n = \frac{1}{n+1}$ for all $n\geq 0.$
By part $(1),$ the set $\{G\subseteq A: \mathbb{P}(G) <  a\}$ is nonempty.
Let 
$$
x_0 = \sup\{\mathbb{P}(G): G\subseteq A, \mathbb{P}(G) < a\}.
$$
Then there exists $G_0\subseteq A$ such that $\mathbb{P}(G_0) < a$ and $x_0(1-\epsilon_0) \leq \mathbb{P}(G_0).$

By using part $(1)$ inductively, for any $n\geq 1,$ let 
$$
x_n = \sup\{\mathbb{P}(G): G\subseteq A\setminus (G_0\cup\cdots G_{n-1}), \mathbb{P}(G_0\cup \cdots G_{n-1} \cup G) < a\}.
$$
Then there exists $G_n\subseteq A\setminus (G_0\cup\cdots G_{n-1})$ such that $\mathbb{P}(G_0\cup \cdots G_{n-1} \cup G_n) < a$ and $x_n(1-\epsilon_n) \leq \mathbb{P}(G_n).$

Let $B = \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty G_n.$
Note that $B\subseteq A,$ $\mathbb{P}\left( \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty G_n\right) \leq a$ and $\{G_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ is mutually disjoint.
So, $\mathbb{P}(B)\leq a.$
By countably additivity of $\mathbb{P},$ we have
$$
\mathbb{P}(B) = \mathbb{P}\left( \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty G_n \right) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb{P}(G_n) \geq \sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n(1-\epsilon_n).
$$
I do not know how to conclude that 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n(1-\epsilon_n) \geq a.$$
Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy I came across the question that you linked above. However, my question here is how to conclude that the summation $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n(1-\epsilon_n) \geq a.$ The solution in the linked post has a different solution than mine.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy It would be good if you can retract your duplicate post as it is really not a duplicate from the question that you linked.

Comment: See also [this closely related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3414100/36150) (I'm not saying that it its a duplicate but i think it's good to link the two questions).

Comment: @saz Yes, I am aware the linked question. However, my question is about my approach, which is different from the question asked there.

Comment: @Idonknow [My answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3414100/prove-that-if-0apra-then-there-exists-b-subset-a-such-that-prb-a/4603441#4603441) to this question should answer your question (thanks to Billingsley!).